# How to remove TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in GLM

Tags: python, python-3.x, glm

I'm trying to fit a GLM model in python 3.1. I'm using `Gaussian` link function. So I wrote

```
import statsmodels.api as sm 
glm=sm(y_train, X_train, family=sm.families.Gaussian())
```

But I'm getting error message

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Can you suggest me how do I deal with this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `sm`, which is a 'module' object, whereas you should be calling `sm.GLM`. Your code should be:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm 
glm=sm.GLM(y_train, X_train, family=sm.families.Gaussian())
```

Check out the official reference for GLMs here: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/glm.html.